# Render superscript in mkdocs

Tags: markdown, mkdocs

Hello I am using Typora as my markdown editor and mkdocs for building the documentation project. While I am using to denote superscript in markdown syntax as

**service_command ^string,mandatory^**

It shows perfectly correct in Typora. But when I build the project using mkdocs the basic html does not show the superscript. I know that manually we can change the html code to display superscript. But I am looking for ways to make mkdocs render superscript correctly. I have also tried to use  tag to achieve the same but mkdocs is unable to render superscript.

Here is the sample HTML code which mkdocs generates

```
<p><strong>service_command</strong>^string, mandatory^
```

Here is the mkdocs generated html page view

[image: mkdocs generated html preview]

Here is how Typora shows the preview

[image: Typora preview]

Answer (score 2):

Figured out that we can also use `<sup></sup>`in Typora instead of using `^string^`for adding superscript

Comment: This is the correct answer. MkDocs uses Markdown and `^` for superscript is not part of Markdown's syntax.